# XAMPP MySQL suddenly doesnt work anymore

Tags: mysql, xampp

It was working fine for month. But today i wanna start working and cant connect to MySQL anymore.

Im using XAMPP 1.7.7 on Windows 7

- XAMPP Control Panel says MySQL is "Running" and shows "Mysql started [Port 3306]"
- But when i go to localhost and click status, it shows "MySQL database Deactivated"
- When i go to phpmyadmin it shows: "2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)"

Also mysql_error.log file at C:\xampp\mysql\data shows no errors?

```
140312 15:02:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140312 15:02:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140312 15:02:24  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140312 15:02:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140312 15:02:25 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 3612444192
140312 15:02:25 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140312 15:02:25 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.16'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Have you tried to shutdown and restart MySQL?

Comment: ofcourse i tried to restart computer and mysql/apache alot

Answer (score 2):

The question is old, but I have just had the same issue so I will write my solution.

It could be a problem with Xampp.
Try to uninstall and install again.
But before, you can try also something that worked for me, namely run the file:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\resetroot.bat
```